# How to set Xcode ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH flag with cmake

Tags: xcode, properties, cmake, target

I can not find any documentation regarding Xcode ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH flag.

Is it possible to set it with cmake?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution by using [SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES) within [XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_](http://cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#prop_tgt%3aXCODE_ATTRIBUTE_an-attribute).

```
set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME}
                      PROPERTIES
                      XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH "YES"
)
```

Comment: If you want set for specific target: `SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(myTarget PROPERTIES XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH[variant=Debug] "YES")`

Comment: I could not get this to work for toplevel (e.g. setting `CMAKE_XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH`) and found out this was the reason why: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22689917/571778